# Overriding footer in local.xml

Tags: layout, magento-1, blocks, theme, overrides

I have a footer in my `page.xml` of my parent theme and here's it's code

```
            <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                <label>Page Footer</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
            <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
        </block>
```

I want to override it in my `local.xml` by changing the template .phtml file, I did that

```
        <reference name="footer">
        <action method="setTemplate">  
            <template>page/html/herzone_footer.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
```

It's not taking any change effect, am I doing something wrong? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks right. Check the following:

- did you add this code within the `default` handle?
- is your theme really active **(design > theme > default and/or design > theme >layout)**?
- did you clean the cache?

Comment: SOLVED, default handle was the answer ,, Thank you man :D